# After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04 system freezes and compiz usage 100% CPU

Tags: upgrade, compiz, 15.04, fullscreen

After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04 system freezes than I run something in fullscreen (Kodi.tv, Steam in Big Picture mode). In htop I'm seeing 99%-102% cpu usage from compiz.

**sudo lshw -C video**

```
      *-display               
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 Ti]
           vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
           version: a1
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
           configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
           resources: irq:35 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
```

**glxinfo | grep -i string**

```
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx version string: 1.4
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 660 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 340.76
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.40 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 340.76
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.40 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 NVIDIA 340.76 340.76
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```

**dpkg-query --show xserver-xorg-video-intel**

```
xserver-xorg-video-intel    2:2.99.917-1~exp1ubuntu2build1
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux ubuH 3.19.1-031901-generic #201504091335 SMP Thu Apr 9 17:36:25 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Other:**
Login screen doesn't show wallpaper and logo, and when I log in on the screen appear artifacts - pieces of windows from previous session ([like here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402061/ubuntu-12-04-pixelated-screen-in-between-login-screen-and-appearance-of-the-desk)). But when I lock system I can see the wallpaper and logo

Comment: Are you using a browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a different desktop.
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell

Or
[Which method should I choose to install GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577093/how-to-install-gnome-desktop)